# Performance guarantee of RLF

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, graph-colorings, approximation-algorithms, heuristics

I cannot manage to find the performance guarantee of the Recursive Largest First (RLF) algorithm for approximating the chromatic number of a graph.

I know DSATUR has a $\mathcal{O}(n)$ guarantee, where $n$ is the number of vertices, and that the best known guarantee is $\mathcal{O}(\frac{n(loglogn)^2}{log^3n})$. I would like to know the guarantee of RLF, as numerical experiments have shown it is very effective in practice.

I do not need a proof, only a reference.

Thank you.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511398/performance-guarantee-of-rlf-algorithm